# Pop-up message with var documents

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a form with pop up message where if the user doesn't fill up the input box nothing will happen and I'm done with that using `required = "required"` of input type number.

What I need is when the input box has been filled a message will pop up and says that the item is added when the button is clicked by the user.

Here's my code:

```
 <label style="color:#000000;">Qty:
 <input type="number" min="1" name="qty" required = "required" />



 SCRIPT:
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
 var a=document.forms["abc"]["qty"].value;
 if (a!=null){
 alert("Item has been successfully added to your Cart");
  }
  }
  </script>




  echo '<td>'.'<input name="but" type="image" value="'.$row3['id'].'"      
  src="images/button.png"  onclick="myFunction()" />'.'</td>';
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? Can You show us form code? Because we don't know if You have form named "abc".
Additionally, I don't know If You just copy & paste Your code, but You missed php open tag <?php before echo.

Comment: oh i see i missed the form abc. You save me oh god. Thanks @Line :)

Comment: OK. So I post this as answer so You could accept :)

Comment: You can also upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the name of form - "abc" - in function myFunction You call element by

```
var a=document.forms["abc"]["qty"].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an id for your input tag.

```
    <label style="color:#000000;">Qty:
 <input type="number" min="1" id="qty" name="qty" required = "required" />



 function myFunction()
 {
 var a=document.forms["abc"]["qty"].value;
    if (a!=null && a!= ""){
     alert("Item has been successfully added to your Cart");
    }
 }
```

Also check for empty fields